# What is the problem with this merge sort algorithm?

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm trying to implement the python code for Merge Sort Algorithm using recursive functions in python. But the code is not working as expected. The value of q in the code is not decreasing as expected of it and is stuck on the 1st value and the function is falling into an infinite recursive function.

```
def merge(A,p,q,r):
    """ This function merges 2 sorted subarrays A[p .. q] and A[q+1 .. r] into a single sorted array A[p .. r]"""
    A1 = A[p:q]
    A2 = A[q:r]
    A1 = A1 + [max(A)+1]
    A2 = A2 + [max(A)+1]
    #print(A1,A2)
    i, j = 0,0
    for k in range(p,r):
        if(A1[i]<=A2[j]):
            A[k] = A1[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            A[k] = A2[j]
            j+=1
        #print(i,j,k)
        #print(A)
    return A

def mrgSort(A,p,r):
    r=len(A)
    if(p<(r-1)):
        q = (p+r)//2
        print(q)
        A1 = mrgSort(A,p,q)
        #print(A)
        A2 = mrgSort(A,q,r)
        #print(A)
        A = [A1,A2]
        merge(A,p,q,r)
        #print(A)  
    return A


print(mrgSort([0,3,2,-1,9,5,6,2,1],0,9))
#print(merge([0,3,5,10,-1,1,5,7,9],0,4,9))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @Rahul Tried it. Didn't find the bug. That's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def merge(A,p,q,r):
    """ This function merges 2 sorted subarrays A[p .. q] and A[q+1 .. r] into a single sorted array A[p .. r]"""
    A1 = A[p:q]
    A2 = A[    q:r]

    A1 = A1 + [(max(A)+1)]
    A2 = A2 + [(max(A)+1)]
    i, j = 0,0
    for k in range(p,r):
         if A1[i]<=A2[j]:
            A[k] = A1[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            A[k] = A2[j]
            j+=1
return A

def mrgSort(A,p,r):
    if(p<(r-1)):
        q = (p+r)//2
        A = mrgSort(A,p,q)
        A = mrgSort(A,q,r)
        A = merge(A,p,q,r)
    return A
```

Some mistakes you make:

- Doing `r=len(A)` resets your variable r every time.
- A = [A1,A2] gives you a list of lists. If you want to concatenate lists, do: `A = A1 + A2`
- Your use of concatenating A1 en A2 was wrong when you look at the way you implemented the algorithm.

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks. Btw can you tell me if we use A=mrgSort(A,p,q) and A=mrgSort(A,q,r) and then using the A in merge() how is A containing both the subarrays? Isn't A just supposed to hold mrgSort(A,q,r) value only?

Comment: That's because we are never slicing A permanently. You use slices of A (A1 and A2) but these are only used to sort the original array A.